# VGA not working on Panasonnic TV

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, vga

Good mornning,

I managed to recover an old PC and want to use on my new TV, but the problem is that the GUI is not seen on television, while on a monitor that works perfectly if the GUI. The PC has a graphics card -> VIA Technologies, Inc. CN700 / P4M800 Pro / P4M800 CE / VN800 [S3 UniChrome Pro] but the truth is I do not know if it is the subject of driver or resolutions. PC OS is Lubuntu 14.04

A greeting and but help me solve this problem

Comment: There's probably no solution. S3 UniChrome Pro were bad even when new and never had a good Linux support. Actually the last release where it seems to work good enough for basic tasks was 12.04.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Okay, but it is that in a 17" monitor does work perfectly, it is when I connect it to 40" television when the GUI stops working. In addition when I install Lubuntu, the GUI work but with a resolution that left read the texts.
for these reasons are why I think it can be an mla resolution setting or something similar